# nest.js in an NX.js project: [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

Tags: angular, nestjs, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a large project that I upgraded to nx.js 14, it is basically a Nest.js backend, 3 Angular 14 apps, a UI Library, a Model Library and it also supports CAPACITOR for the mobile versions of one of the Angular App.

When compiling the nest.js project I get the following error:

```
chunk (runtime: main) main.js (main) 391 KiB (javascript) 937 bytes (runtime) [entry] [rendered]
webpack compiled successfully (964121f2aac59057)
Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/8a3004b3-4c99-46d7-a548-4708fb498474
Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/8a3004b3-4c99-46d7-a548-4708fb498474
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@nrwl/node/src/executors/node/node-with-require-overrides.js:16
        return originalLoader.apply(this, arguments);
                              ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Function.Module._load (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@nrwl/node/src/executors/node/node-with-require-overrides.js:16:31)
    at Object.@angular/common (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:10631:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:10809:41)
    at Object../apps/c4g-api/src/services/bank/bank.service.ts (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:3744:73)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:10809:41)
    at Object../apps/c4g-api/src/services/admin/admin.service.ts (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:3353:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:10809:41)
    at Object../apps/c4g-api/src/controllers/profiles/care-seeker-profile/care-seeker-profile.controller.ts (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:2284:87)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:10809:41)
    at Object../apps/c4g-api/src/app.module.ts (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:63:131)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:10809:41)
    at /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:10863:69
    at /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:10881:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/dist/apps/c4g-api/main.js:10886:12)
    at Function.Module._load (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@nrwl/node/src/executors/node/node-with-require-overrides.js:16:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@nrwl/node/src/executors/node/node-with-require-overrides.js:19:1)
```

However, I am not using require() anywhere. I am a bit stomped.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "nx-c4g",
  "version": "1.6.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "nx",
    "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2018 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
    "nx": "nx",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "nx workspace-lint && ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "affected:apps": "nx affected:apps",
    "affected:libs": "nx affected:libs",
    "affected:build": "nx affected:build",
    "affected:e2e": "nx affected:e2e",
    "affected:test": "nx affected:test",
    "affected:lint": "nx affected:lint",
    "affected:dep-graph": "nx affected:dep-graph",
    "affected": "nx affected",
    "format": "nx format:write",
    "format:write": "nx format:write",
    "format:check": "nx format:check",
    "update": "nx migrate latest",
    "workspace-generator": "nx workspace-generator",
    "dep-graph": "nx dep-graph",
    "help": "nx help"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@alyle/ui": "13.2.2",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.0.2",
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "14.0.0-beta.40",
    "@angular/forms": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "14.1.0",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^1.3.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.6.0",
    "@capacitor/geolocation": "^1.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "latest",
    "@google-cloud/logging-bunyan": "4.1.1",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "latest",
    "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js": "^3.1.16",
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "1.6.7",
    "@nestjs/axios": "^0.1.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.5",
    "@nestjs/config": "2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.5",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.5",
    "@ng-idle/core": "11.1.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "11.0.3",
    "@ngrx/effects": "14.0.2",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "14.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "14.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "14.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "7.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/next": "^14.4.3",
    "@nxtend/capacitor": "13.0.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^14.1.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.4",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.15.0",
    "@types/google.maps": "latest",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.15",
    "core-js": "^3.23.5",
    "debug": "^4.3.2",
    "devextreme": "21.1.3",
    "devextreme-angular": "21.1.3",
    "devextreme-schematics": "^1.2.15",
    "firebase": "7.24.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "gm": "latest",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.7",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.23",
    "nestjs-command": "latest",
    "nestjs-stripe": "^0.4.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.10",
    "ngx-input-file": "10.2.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "10.1.1",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^6.1.1",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^10.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "pusher": "^5.0.0",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "latest",
    "rrule": "^2.6.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.6",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stripe": "^8.148.0",
    "swiper": "^6.6.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.1.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.6.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.6.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.6.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.5",
    "@nrwl/angular": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/cli": "^14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/nest": "^14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/node": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/tao": "^14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.8",
    "@types/stripe-checkout": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.19.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "cypress": "^6.0.1",
    "devextreme-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "devextreme-themebuilder": "^20.2.5",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "eslint": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jest": "26.2.2",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.4.0",
    "ng-packagr": "12.2.7",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.5",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

And my nx report

```
>  NX   Report complete - copy this into the issue template

   Node : 16.16.0
   OS   : darwin x64
   npm  : 6.14.12
   
   nx : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/angular : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/cypress : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/detox : Not Found
   @nrwl/devkit : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/express : Not Found
   @nrwl/jest : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/js : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/linter : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/nest : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/next : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/node : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/nx-cloud : Not Found
   @nrwl/nx-plugin : Not Found
   @nrwl/react : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/react-native : Not Found
   @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
   @nrwl/storybook : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/web : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/workspace : 14.4.3
   typescript : 4.7.4
   ---------------------------------------
   Community plugins:
         @alyle/ui: 13.2.2
         @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome: 0.9.0
         @ngrx/effects: 14.0.2
         @ngrx/schematics: 14.0.2
         @ngrx/store: 14.0.2
         @ngrx/store-devtools: 14.0.2
         @nxtend/capacitor: 13.0.0
         devextreme-angular: 21.1.3
         devextreme-schematics: 1.4.2
```

Comment: Updating nest.js to 9 doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in my nest.js backend, I was using CurrencyPipe to do some currency formatting, which is from @angular/common when in fact I should have been using `Intl.NumberFormat`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue for me the problem is a bad auto import on a NestJs service:

> import { Injectable } from '@angular/common';

Instead of:

> import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';